# I am Getting 404 Error after uploading images in webp format

Tags: image, webp

I am getting a 404 error after uploading .webp images.

I have so many 404 errors on such pages.

Error is in this formate: **url/image/webp**

Please look into the matter and provide a valuable solution.

Thanks,
Uttara

I am not a technical girl, so could not do anything.

I want you guys to look into the matter and provide solutions if any.